# How to set neon-animation fill mode

Tags: polymer-1.0

It is not mentioned either in the documentation nor in the demos how to set fill mode in `animationConfig` object,

I've tried

```
fill: 'both'

timing: {
  fill: 'both'
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: Actually the fill is already set to both. The problem is explained in this post stackoverflow.com/questions/31692377/how-to-maintain-the-end-state-of-a-neon-animation-in-polymer